# Database path from text file

Tags: vb.net

I was trying to give path of the database from text file but `SqlConnection` didn't recognize this.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim server As String = ""
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(server)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        con.open()
        Dim file2 As String = "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\yes.DAT"
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(file2)
        server = reader.ReadToEnd
        MessageBox.Show(server)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can you provide some clarity here please, what is the contents of the file you are loading?

Comment: As it is, you are opening the file and reading the contents, but not closing the file. If you are going to use a `StreamReader` then create it with a `Using` statement, so that it will be closed automatically. In this case though, just call `File.ReadAllText`, which will do all the opening, reading and closing internally and simply pass you the text that was read, i.e. `Dim connectionString = File.ReadAllText(filePath)`.

Comment: It is customary to store connection strings in the application config file. There is built-in functionality to read them from there. It is an XML file so it is hand-editable if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dim con As New SqlConnection(server)` happens when the class is constructed but `Form1_Load` doesn't happen until *after* the class is constructed. You need to reverse the order.

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Dim server As String = ""
    Dim con As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Using reader As New StreamReader("C:\Users\alex\Desktop\yes.DAT")
            con = New SqlConnection(reader.ReadToEnd())
        End Using
        con.open()
    End Sub
End Class
```

However, I would declare a SqlConnection at class level and not keep it open like this. You should open it with a `Using` block and do what you need with it inside, before the `End Using` so it gets disposed when you're done with it, similar to what I did with your `StreamReader`.

Comment: So sorry! I didn't catch that. You clearly state that. I will delete my comment in a bit. Love the handsome ? (beautiful?) dog.

Comment: @Mary thank you, he passed away 3 months ago sadly :(

Comment: Very sorry. I understand your grief. I still mourn my Great Danes that passed away almost 30 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the `SqlConnection` object while the value of `server` is still an empty `String`. You also try to open that connection before reading the connection string from the file. You need to either create the connection or set the `ConnectionString` property after you read the connection string, then open it.

Answer (score 0):

I used the File class to read the file.

Please don't use form level variables for connections and commands. They need to be closed and disposed after each use. The connection String is fine at the form level. You may want to use it in several methods and, after all, it is just a string and doesn't need to be disposed in code.

```
Private conString As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    conString = File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\alex\Desktop\yes.DAT")
End Sub

Private Sub RetrieveData()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(conString),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From SomeTable;", cn)
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Comment: @Alex If my answer provided a solution, please accept is by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.